# mvc 4 custom displaytemplates using display annotation and resources

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, enums, display-templates

I'm trying to create custom display template for Enum `Status` with name text loaded from resources specified by class member annotation. I've achieved simple loading of display template using `@Html.DisplayFor(...)`. But I don't know how to display `Name` loaded from resources (specified in `ResourcesType`, `Display` annotation class member)

Code:

`~Views/Shared/DisplayTemplate/Row.cshtml`

```
    @using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
    @model LeasePlan.Nadmerne_opotrebeni.WebUI.Controllers.Status

    @{
        var field = Model.GetType().GetField(Model.ToString());
        if (field != null)
        {
            var display = ((DisplayAttribute[])field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false)).FirstOrDefault() as DisplayAttribute;

            if (display != null)
            {
                <span class="label status label-info">@((display.Name as string).ToUpper())</span>
            }
        }
    }
```

`Enum Status`

```
public enum Status
{
    [Display(Name = "STATUS_LOADING", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.LabelsResources))]
    Loading = 1,

    [Display(Name = "STATUS_DISABLED", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.LabelsResources))]
    Disabled = 2,
}
```

//edit : my solution

I've found solution, but I don't feel good about it... Isn't there any better way?

`~Views/Shared/DisplayTemplate/Row.cshtml`

```
    @using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
    @model LeasePlan.Nadmerne_opotrebeni.WebUI.Controllers.Status

    @{
        var field = Model.GetType().GetField(Model.ToString());
        if (field != null)
        {
        dynamic resourcesManager = display.ResourceType.GetProperty("ResourceManager").GetValue(null, null);

        var name = resourcesManager.GetString(display.Name as string);

        <span class="label status label-info">@(name != null ? name.ToUpper() : name)</span>   
        }
    }
```